# Unable to get VeeValidate 3.x working with a custom component using VueSelect

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate, vue-select

This is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-with-vueselect-13g9d

I'm using a custom component because I want to override a couple of slots in VueSelect. I'm using the `ValidationProvider` but that doesn't seem to be working.

I've looked for help but only found examples using VeeValidate 2.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out how it works. By default, VeeValidate validates the input only after the `blur` or `input` events on the child elements of `ValidationProvider`. If you want it to validate on custom events, you can implement a custom mode for the custom component and specify the `mode` attribute on the `ValidationProvider`.

For example: https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-with-vueselect-13g9d (my updated codesandbox link).